# How to check and update existing contact using apex?

Tags: apex

We are one custom object"Data feed" where user enter their detail.Then using batch apex we are inserting these record as a contact. First I need to check whether the contact is already exist or not. If exist then I need to update the contact else need to create new contact. I can insert the contact but i got stucked when checking for existing contact. Here is the code what i have tried, using this code i can insert the contact but can't able to update the existing contact. Kindly advice me how to achieve this.

```
  global class ScheduleContact implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
global Database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {

    String query = 'Select Name,Account_ID__c,Primary_Account_ID__c, Deleted__c, First_Name__c, Internal_User_ID__c,Language_Preference__c,Language_Preference_Code__c,Phone__c,Primary_Contact__c,Speaks_English__c from Data_Feeds__c';


    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {

    List<Data_Feeds__c> feeds = (List<Data_Feeds__c>) scope;

    Set<String> lastNames = new Set<String>();
    for (Data_Feeds__c f : feeds) {
        lastNames.add(f.Name);
    }

    Map<String, Contact> contacts = new Map<String, Contact>();
    for (Contact c : [select Id, LastName from Contact where LastName in :lastNames])
     {
        contacts.put(c.LastName, c);
    }
    for (Data_Feeds__c f : feeds) {
        Contact c;
       // Contact c = new Contact();
        if (contacts.containsKey(f.Name)) {
            c = contacts.get(f.Name);
        } else {
            c = new Contact(LastName = f.Name);
            contacts.put(f.Name, c);
        }
        c.FirstName = f.First_Name__c;
        c.AccountId = f.Primary_Account_ID__c;
        c.AccContRole__c = f.Account_ID__c;
    }
    upsert contacts.values();
/********************************Insert Account Contact Roles************************************/
    List<Contact> AccConRole = new List<Contact>();
    Set<ID> AccID = new Set<ID>(); 

    for (Contact con : contacts.values())
    {
      AccID.add(con.AccContRole__c);
     }

    Map<ID,AccountContactRole> controle = new Map<ID,  AccountContactRole>();
    for (AccountContactRole ACR :[ SELECT Id,ContactId, Role From  AccountContactRole WHERE ContactId in :AccID])
    {
        controle.put(ACR.ContactId, ACR);
    }
    for (Contact con : contacts.values())
    {
        AccountContactRole ACR;
            if(controle.containsKey(con.AccContRole__c))
            {
                ACR = controle.get(con.AccContRole__c);
            }
            else 
            {
                ACR = new AccountContactRole( ContactId = con.AccContRole__c);
                controle.put(con.AccContRole__c, ACR);
            }
            ACR.ContactId = con.AccContRole__c;
            ACR.AccountId  = con.AccountId;

    }
    upsert controle.Values();

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

}
}
```

Comment: Your match to existing Contacts is based solely on the Contact.LastName?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it is just the Contact.LastName that identifies a Contact and that there are no duplicates, this (untested) code will insert or update (by using upsert) as necessary:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {

    List<Data_Feeds__c> feeds = (List<Data_Feeds__c>) scope;

    Set<String> lastNames = new Set<String>();
    for (Data_Feeds__c f : feeds) {
        lastNames.add(f.Name);
    }

    Map<String, Contact> contacts = new Map<String, Contact>();
    for (Contact c : [
            select Id, LastName
            from Contact
            where LastName in :lastNames
            ]) {
        contacts.put(c.LastName, c);
    }
    for (Data_Feeds__c f : feeds) {
        Contact c;
        if (contacts.containsKey(f.Name)) {
            c = contacts.get(f.Name);
        } else {
            c = new Contact(LastName = f.Name);
            contacts.put(f.Name, c);
        }
        c.FirstName = f.First_Name__c;
        c.AccountId = f.Primary_Account_ID__c;
        c.AccContRole__c = f.Account_ID__c;
    }
    upsert contacts.values();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its working now. In this i have added the same insert and update function for Contact role.but it showing some error:First error: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [ContactId]: [ContactId]. I have edited my code.

Comment: @user7292 You might get that error is a Data_Feeds__c .Account_ID__c was ever null. Also code like `WHERE ContactId in :AccID` looks wrong: are you sure you are using the correct IDs everywhere?